# Translating a handwritten Ireland baptism record

Tags: palaeography, baptism-records, ireland, translation

I have a record of Martin Ryan baptism by Rootsireland record but it doesn't have everything the original document has.

**Rootsireland record**:

[image: Rootsireland record]

**Registers.nli.ie record** (https://registers.nli.ie/registers/vtls000632759#page/40/mode/1up):

[image]

1) What is the full translation of day 22?

---

**Civil Record** (https://civilrecords.irishgenealogy.ie/churchrecords/images/birth_returns/births_1865/03552/2307836.pdf):
[image]

2) I need help translating a couple of words on the Civil document. Under "name and surname ... of mother" it says "Mary Ryan" something "Hayes". Anyone know what the word is?

Also under "Signature, Qualification and Residence..." it says something (the?) "Jeremiah" something "Ryan" something (moth?) "father Drumwood".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parish register is in Latin. This is far from unusual in Roman Catholic registers from rural Irish parishes. The Irish Genealogy Toolkit has a useful page on [Latin in Irish Catholic parish registers](https://www.irish-genealogy-toolkit.com/latin-irish-parish-registers.html).

In this example, the entry for the 22nd reads:

> Martinus fl Jeremiah Ryan et Maria Hayes Sp Martinus Corbet et Maria L____ Drumwood

Which translates to:

> Martin, legitimate son of Jeremiah Ryan and Mary Hayes of Drumwood; Godparents Martin Corbet & Mary L____

The L____ might be the Irish surname "Looney", but I can't be certain as the letter forms don't quite match.

---

The entry from the civil register:

Under "**Name and Surname and Maiden Surname of Mother**" it looks like it says

> Mary Ryan
>  
>   formerly
>   Hayes

although the word "formerly" is not very well written in this example.

Under "**Signature, Qualification and Residence of Informant**"

> The
>  
>   Jeremiah X Ryan
>  
>   mark
>  
>   father
>  
>   Drumwood

(The X is the name is Jeremiah's mark. Like many at that date he was illiterate).

Comment: Haha funny I've been trying to read Latin. No wonder I had trouble :)

Comment: If the Irish GRO rules were anything like those for the English and Welsh GRO, names have to follow a rigorous formula, so although the "formerly" here is a bit of a scribble, there's basically nothing else it could be. Which may account for why it's a scribble - meaning was obvious to those who knew the rules.

Comment: @AdrianB38 The Irish rules were the same ("formerly" for surname at birth and "late" for a previous married surname), but I've less experience with Irish central registration records, so I'm not sure how rigorously it was enforced.